# Message Queue routing patterns across data centers?

Tags: .net, azure, service, message-queue

So I'm writing in C# using Azure Service Bus, but those details don't matter so much, as I'm looking for a design pattern, not a code chunk. We have client data across several data centres, and we (can/will) have multiple worker processes in those data centres. What I'm trying to do is have the ability to take a list of clients, split them out by data centre (unique identifiers) and do some work with the client's data using the workers that are in the same data centre so we aren't dragging massive amounts of data all across the continent.

I'm leaning towards having a separate queue for each data centre, but if we choose that as our design pattern, we'd very quickly run in to massive numbers of queues to monitor, one per operation per warehouse. I'd thought of topics (multicast filtered pub/sub) but then you have to route to workers at the data centre level, and your router service starts becoming a bottleneck for requests coming in to the data centre.

Another issue is minimizing configuration duplication: How does a worker know what data centre it's in and what queues it should be looking for? How do the message creators know what queues to use? Do they need to be data centre aware with respect to routing their own messages? Should they be?

I had a lot of trouble finding any other information on message queueing patterns that spanned data centres, so I'm hoping someone has a bit of experience they'd be willing to share.

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something but could you try to use Azure ServiceBus brokered messaging?

1. define a custom property to populate the datacenter info
2. post messages for each new work items with property populated with specific datacenter
3. have worker filter by this property depending on which datacenter they are located in
4. process only those messages that are related to their datacenter

BrokeredMessaging: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh532019.aspx

Comment: I was under the impression that subscribers could only filter on Topics, not Queues. I haven't found any documentation on filtering by subscribers in Queues. Filtering on topics is possible, but topics are broadcast, they don't support competing consumers.